Streamlit Javascript integration
I can't get any js function in streamlit (python) to work, the return value is always 0, no matter how I tried to write it. For instance
anonymous = st_javascript("""
    (() => {
        return 2;
    })()
""")

st.write(f"JavaScript returned: {anonymous}")

What am I doing wrong here? Chatgpt and claude couldn't help, nor did I see any helpfull posts here.
Can someone provide the correct syntax?

correct syntax for what? python? javascript? "streamlit"?

@JaromandaX The js code within the """, so the python variable anonymous gets the intended value.

the code within """ returns 2 - so the javascript syntax is correct. as for python and/or "streamlit" - I can't help - but at least you know the javascript is correct. 1 down, 2 to go
